# Can't find correctly node and npm instances in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I've a problem for use the node and npm install in my linux.

This hade started when in a project that I work, it have some problems with my global node, I don't remember what was my version, but the project is 10.13.0 and I could't build it.

So,I installed the version with .taz with below steps:

1. apt autoremove nodejs
2. extract `.taz` for `/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64`
3. put path in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` (found in net)

```
export NODEJS_HOME=/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/bin
export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME:$PATH
```

4. executed `. ~/.profile ~/.bashrc`

Well, after that my node -v worked but node hello got this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/gustavo-rey/Área de Trabalho/vue-curso/vue-cli/bla'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3
```

However, my npm stoped to work with this error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/npm: File or directory not found
```

Can you help with this? I can't change my node version...

**Resolution**

With the Jatin's help, I could install the correctly version with sudo n [version.number], however, I've needed to remove my old aplication from the $PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/bin:/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- clear the npm cache:

  ```
  npm cache clean -f
  ```
- Install n, Node’s version manager:

  > npm install -g n
- With the n module installed, you can use it to:

  ```
   Install the latest stable version: sudo n stable
   Install the latest release: sudo n latest
   Install a specific version: sudo n [version.number]
  ```

For the permissions

first check the **permissions** of `/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n`( please check if its the correct path) by using this command

```
ls -la /opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n
```

**pretty sure it might be owned by root or some other user**.

Then run `whoami`

and finally

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n
```

Comment: npm --version and node--version what output these 2 commands give?

Comment: I managed to remap the npm, now it is working, however, when I try to npm install -g n I get this message:

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/n\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES'

Comment: Updated my answer, with the fix to the recent error, if it helped you, accept this as a solution to your answer so that it may help others in the future.